# Получение всех ссылок на определенный тип файла со страницы

Tags: php

Нужен метод (или как они там называются) на PHP, который возвращает список всех ссылок на файлы с заданным расширением (допустим, mp3). На пыхе не писал, не знаю, как там с этим.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно и с другого сайта. Вам тогда нужен парсер.

- cURL 'ом или file_get_content() получеаете код страницы.
- Регуляркой проверяете все ссылки.

http://sitear.ru/material/php-parsing-html-simple-html-dom

Answer (score 0):

в PHP с этим хорошо.

```
//Имя директории, в которой ищем. Если надо в нескольких, можно сделать цикл или рекурсию.
$directory_name = 'path/to/directory';
//Список расширений. СОбственно, может приходить извне в виде строки через запятую.
$extensions = array_flip(explode(',','mp3,xlsx,psd'));

//Получаем список всех файлов в директории
$all_files = scandir($directory_name);
$selected_files = array();

foreach($all_files as $file){
  if(isset($extensions[filename_extension(file)])){
    $selected_files[] = $directory_name.'/'.$file;
  }
}

//ВЫВОД СПИСКА ФАЙЛОВ
print(implode(',<br/>',$selected_files));
//Можно вывести прямо сразу ссылки:
foreach($selected_files as $file){
  printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>','http://example.com/'.$file,$file);
}

function filename_extension($filename) {
    $pos = strrpos($filename, '.');
    if($pos===false) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return substr($filename, $pos+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Думаю, вопрос был о парсере страницы в интернете, а не директорий на сервере...

Comment: если ув.тов. @myvzar прав, то никак в общем случае)

Comment: Да и вообще, Ваш код можно сократить
$files = glob('*.{php,txt}', GLOB_BRACE);